# How to improve str check on false?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a varaible:

```
public searchValue: string;
```

And conditions that checks if variable is not empty:

```
const searchQuery = this.searchValue && 
  this.searchValue.toString().trim().length ? 
    `appname[like]${this.searchValue.toString().trim()}` : 
    null;

if (!searchQuery) return;
```

How to improve this `if`?

Comment: More shortly, because as you can see I make twicw toString and trim

Comment: Do you use `searchQuery` anywhere else besides in your if condition? What is the purpose of the ternary

Comment: Yes, I use, I can replace  ternary but what is benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter and easier to read

I am using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to not get an error when trying to trim null/undefined

```js
const val = this.searchValue?.trim();
const searchQuery = val.length ? `appname[like]${val}` : null;
if (!searchQuery) return; // note: return needs to be in a function
```

Answer (score 1):

`searchValue` is a string, so it doesn't have a `.toString()` method :) Just check for :

```
typeof searchValue === "string" && searchValue.trim().length;
```

Comment: I need to use `trim()` how to apply this

Comment: I added it while you were asking ;)